# How would I handle input with a Game Component?

Tags: xna, input

I am currently having problems from finding my way into the component-oriented XNA design.

I read an overview over [the general design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) and googled a lot of XNA examples. However, they seem to be right on the opposite site. In the general design pattern, an object (my current player) is passed to `InputComponent::update(Player)`. This means the class will know what to do and how this will affect the game (e.g. move person vs. scroll text in a menu).

Yet, in XNA `GameComponent::update(GameTime)` is called automatically without a reference to the current player.

The only XNA examples I found built some sort of higher-level Keyboard engine into the game component like this:

```
class InputComponent: GameComponent
{
    public void keyReleased(Keys);
    public void keyPressed(Keys);
    public bool keyDown(Keys);

    public void override update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // compare previous state with current state and
        // determine if released, pressed, down or nothing
    }
 }
```

Some others went a bit further making it possible to use a Service Locator by a design like this:

```
interface IInputComponent
{
    public void downwardsMovement(Keys);
    public void upwardsMovement(Keys);
    public bool pausedGame(Keys);

    // determine which keys pressed and what that means
    // can be done for different inputs in different implementations
    public void override update(GameTime);
 }
```

Yet, then I am wondering if it is possible to design an input class to resolve all possible situations. Like in a menu a mouse click can mean "click that button", but in game play it can mean "shoot that weapon".

So if I am using such a modular design with game components for input, how much logic is to be put into the InputComponent / KeyboardComponent / GamepadComponent and where is the rest handled?

What I had in mind, when I heard about Game Components and Service Locator in XNA was something like this:

- use Game Components to run the InputHandler automatically in the loop
- use Service Locator to be able to switch input at runtime (i.e. let player choose if he wants to use a gamepad or a keyboard; or which shall be player 1 and which player 2).

However, now I cannot see how this can be done.

- First code example does not seem flexible enough, as on a game pad you could require some combination of buttons for something that is possible on keyboard with only one button or with the mouse)
- The second code example seems really hard to implement, because the InputComponent has to know in which context we are currently. Moreover, you could imagine your application to be multi-layered and let the key-stroke go through all layers to the bottom-layer which requires a different behaviour than the InputComponent would have guessed from the top-layer.
- The general design pattern with passing the `Player` to `update()` does not have a representation in XNA and I also cannot see how and where to decide which class should be passed to `update()`. At most time of course the player, but sometimes there could be menu items you have to or can click

I see that the question in general is already [dealt with here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5731/do-i-and-how-separate-the-concerns-of-input-and-game-objects), but probably from a more elobate point-of-view. At least, I am not smart enough in game development to understand it. I am searching for a rather code-based example directly for XNA.

And the answer there leaves (a noob like) me still alone in how the object that should receive the detected event is chosen. Like if I have a key-up event, should it go to the text box or to the player?

Comment: It's rather important to point out that XNA's `GameComponent` implements a ***completely different*** pattern to the component-matrix design described in the article you linked (and [this one](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/)). You should implement your own base class and component collection(s) to meet your needs. See also: [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) (especially my comment reply to BlueRaja) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrestled with this myself -- how to create a simple component/entity framework for XNA. Here's what I did; my goals were:

- Create reusable components (reusable within and across games) that are generic
- Create game-specific entities that encapsulate "business domain" logic of my game

I ended up creating a basic `Entity` class (behind an interface):

```
public interface IEntity
    {
        void Update(double elapsedSeconds);        
        bool HasComponent<T>() where T : IComponent;
        T GetComponent<T>() where T : IComponent;
    }
```

My `Player` class, enemies, etc. all subclass from this. My components also live behind an interface with a simple `Update` method. Most of them expose specific functionality (eg. for input, events for when keys/mouse are pressed).

Creating the player was simple:

```
public class Player : Entity {
  public Player() {
    var input = new InputComponent();
    input.OnPress += (key) => {
      if (key == Keys.Space) { this.Jump(); }
    }
    this.addComponent(input);
  }
}
```

My input component reads keyboard input only. I personally created a different component for handling mouse input, although it could be the same. Tomorrow, I can always extend my input component to expose an event for when a gamepad button is pressed.

In this way, components really encapsulate only their specific piece of functionality, and I can easily reuse them across games; while entities are game-specific, and probably won't be reused; at the same time, it's easy to see where the "game logic" lives.

As for service locators, I think that amount of indirection is probably overkill for a small or medium-sized project. I would start with something a bit simpler first.

Comment: What are HasComponent and GetComponent used for? It does not seem they are needed for functionality; but you mentioned them, so I guess they are important?

Comment: @Aufziehvogel it's up to you how you implement that. My entities all have a generic list of components, but you could as easily keep references in your entities to the components they have. You can find more general stuff in this awesome article: gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html ("How does the object get its components?")